# What happened when I use keytool -genkeypair without -alias?

Tags: keytool, gnome-terminal

I wrote the following command on terminal:

> keytool -genkeypair

I answered the questions, but nothing happened next. I saw on internet people doing that, but using -alias. Now I'm afraid that I might have done something wrong. Did I do? Can I see what I have generate and delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default alias keytool uses is `mykey`. If the command succeeded, it generated with the default alias. You can confirm that by looking into the contents of the keystore, with this command:

> keytool -list -keystore [KEYSTORE] -storepass [KEYSTORE_PASSWORD]

If you wish to delete that entry:

> keytool -delete -alias [ALIAS] -keystore [KEYSTORE] -storepass [KEYSTORE_PASSWORD]